# Convert plain text to have i tags inside p tags

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Im working with HtmlAgilityPack in C# and im presented with plain p-tagless text.
I've already wrote an extension that lets me add `p` tags around p-tagless text, but when i get `text<i>foo</i>text` in the p-tagless text, it turns into `<p>text</p><i><p>foo</p></i><p>text</p>`.

How do i convert this:

`text<i>another piece of text</i>text`

into this:

`<p>text<i>another piece of text</i>text</p>`

here is my extension:

```
    private static readonly string[] unacceptableParents = { "p", "a", "i", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6" };`

    public static HtmlDocument AddPTagAroundTextWithoutTag(this HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        GetXPathOfText(doc, doc.DocumentNode);

        return doc;
    }
    public static void AddPTags(HtmlDocument doc, HtmlNode node)
    {
        var tekstName = "#text";
        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (var thisNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (thisNode.ChildNodes.Any())
                {
                    GetXPathOfText(doc, thisNode);
                }
                else if (thisNode.Name == tekstName && !unacceptableParents.Contains(thisNode.ParentNode.Name))
                {
                    thisNode.Name = "p";
                    thisNode.InnerHtml = "<p>" + node.InnerText.Trim() + "</p>";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.Name == tekstName && !unacceptableParents.Contains(node.ParentNode.Name))
            {
                node.Name = "p";
                node.InnerHtml = "<p>" + node.InnerText.Trim() + "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just do `AddPTags(doc, doc.DocumentNode)` and that's it?

Comment: hahaha youre right xD didnt even notice that, but that doesnt fix the i tags, those still get seperated

Comment: And after you changed it is it still doing adding too many `p` tags? Maybe delete the whole `if` branch in `AddPTags` and leave only the `else` part? I don't see why the node having children matters here.

Comment: Its a recursive function so thats why i have that if, the example i gave with the i tag is just a part of the HTML it can be pages full of HTML i need to convert. Only, the client cant add p tags in their editor, so i need to convert all the HTML to have p tags. But i tags seperate the text so it is not included in the p tags and it handles it as a different tag